# Javascript: How to assign to a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I've got the following code:

```
$('#sample_1').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { "bSortable": false }
    ],
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 30, 100, -1],
        [10, 30, 100, "Alle"] // change per page values here
    ],
    // set the initial value
    "iDisplayLength": 30,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge",
        "sSearch": "Suche: ",
        "sInfo": "Einträge _START_ bis _END_ von insgesamt _TOTAL_ angezeigt",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Vorherige",
            "sNext": "Nächste"
        }
    }
});
```

And I want to reuse some of the parameters in other tables, and thus assign it to a variable. I tried:

```
myVar = {// set the initial value
    "iDisplayLength": 30,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge",
        "sSearch": "Suche: ",
        "sInfo": "Einträge _START_ bis _END_ von insgesamt _TOTAL_ angezeigt",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Vorherige",
            "sNext": "Nächste"
        }
    }};
$('#sample_1').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { "bSortable": false }
    ],
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 30, 100, -1],
        [10, 30, 100, "Alle"] // change per page values here
    ],
    myVar
});
```

but this doesnt work. Can you please give me some advise? 
Tried googleing, but don't know how this `contruct` is being called, aren't those simple arrays are they? EDIT: Seem to be some sort of objects, but how to actrually pass the attributes of this object then as a parameter to dataTable?

Thanks a lot

Comment: use `var myVar='something' `. thats the syntax for defining a variable if its not predefined , in your case , i dont know if u have defined it previously like that or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

You are trying to assign 3 parameters using one object.

Something like this will do the trick.

```
var myVar = {
    "iDisplayLength": 30,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge",
        "sSearch": "Suche: ",
        "sInfo": "Einträge _START_ bis _END_ von insgesamt _TOTAL_ angezeigt",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Vorherige",
            "sNext": "Nächste"
        }
    }
};

$('#sample_1').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { "bSortable": false }
    ],
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 30, 100, -1],
        [10, 30, 100, "Alle"] // change per page values here
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": myVar.iDisplayLength,
    "sPaginationType" myVar.sPaginationType,
    "oLanguage": myVar.oLanguage
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need 3 variables for this as there are 3 separate values (parallel):

```
1// "iDisplayLength": 30,
   2// "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
   3// "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge",
        "sSearch": "Suche: ",
        "sInfo": "Einträge _START_ bis _END_ von insgesamt _TOTAL_ angezeigt",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Vorherige",
            "sNext": "Nächste"
        }
```

I think you are confused by all those curly braces, but you are on the right track.

Comment: Sure? Why isn't it possible to use only one variable and store it all there? In fact, the complete argument-list to `dataTable` actually looks like ONE big argument packed into curly braces as well...!?

Comment: What would this variable be assigned to ? It would work if it took a big parameter object, but that `dataTable` does not work like this. See other answer, you still need 3 separate entries even if the values come from the same variable.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought there might be some sort of method to convert the object `myVar` to single arguments automatically :)